# how to use a loop within a functions parameter and log the result to the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, for-loop

The goal I am trying to achieve is to use `jQuery` to collect, all the `CLASS` `css` stylings of any `HTML` page and then loop through each of the `classes` and gather the `height`, `width`, `top` and `left` of each `class`, which I'll then put into an `Array` and log it to the console.

Below is where I am currently at with the code. I'm able to gather all the page `classes`, but struggling to loop through them to give me the `height`, `width`, `top` and `left` of each `class`. Below is the code, would anyone be able to guide me in the right direction or possible give an example on how to build it?. Any help will be appreciated :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // VARIABLES
    var allClassNames = [];
    var eachClassName = "";

    // GET CLASS NAMES FROM THE HTML PAGE
    $('[class]').each(function eachClassName(){

        $.each($(this).attr('class').split(' '), function(i, className) {
            if (className.length && $.inArray(className, allClassNames) === -1) {
                allClassNames.push(className);
            }
        });

    });

    // GET THE CSS STYLING FOR EACH CLASS
    function getStyleRuleValue(style, selector) {

        for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
            var mysheet = document.styleSheets[i];
            var myrules = mysheet.cssRules ? mysheet.cssRules : mysheet.rules;

            for (k = 0; k < allClassNames.length; k++) {
                console.log(allClassNames[k]);
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < myrules.length; j++) {
                if (myrules[j].selectorText && myrules[j].selectorText.toLowerCase() === selector) {
                    return myrules[j].style[style];
                }
            }
        }

    };

    // I'M TRYING TO LOOP THROUGH THE CLASSES WHERE IT SAYS .TWO??
    console.log( getStyleRuleValue('top', '.two') );

});
```

Comment: You know you can do this with just `$('.two').css('top')` ?

Comment: @adeneo is giving valuable insight for this problem! And even better, you can send an array of css property names to jquery, and it will spit out the values for each of them. That means the following works: `$('.two').css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height'])`

Comment: Thanks guys means alot :) but if there was more than one class on a HTML page. How would I be able to loop through all of them, showing the values Would this work? $(allClassNames[k]).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height'])

Comment: `$(allClassNames).each(function() {...`

Comment: I tried the following but keep getting undefined in the console, what have i done wrong?:    $(allClassNames).each(function() {
 console.log( $(allClassNames[k]).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height']) );
 });

Comment: use `$("." + allClassNames.join(",."))` intead `$(allClassNames)`. Look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/g125f56c/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much elchininet, adeneno and Gershom. your solutions have helped me.. Again thank you very much!! :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that ;) I've added the link at the comment to the answer. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix `jQuery` and `JavaScript` pure code, if you are using `jQuery` use its methods:

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="div1 value1"></div>
<div class="div1 value2"></div>
<div class="div1 value3"></div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.value1{
  top: 100px;
}

.value2{
  top: 200px;
}

.value3{
  top: 300px;
}
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
function getStyleRuleValue(style, selector){

    $("." + selector).each(function(){

        console.log( $(this).css(style) );

    }); 

}

getStyleRuleValue("top", "div1");
// 100px
// 200px
// 300px
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/2wm3d4yc/1/)

**EDIT:**

If you want to use the allClassNames `Array` with all the page classes (You do not need this `Array` to iterate into all page elements):

```
var allClassNames = [];

$("[class]").each(function eachClassName(){

    $.each($(this).attr("class").split(" "), function(i, className) {

        if (className.length && $.inArray(className, allClassNames) === -1) {

            allClassNames.push(className);

        }

    });

});

$("." + allClassNames.join(",.")).each(function(){

     console.log( $(this).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height']) );

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/g125f56c/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by building a map of selectors to styles, based on the stylesheets, and then use that to look up each of the classes I found on the document.

```
function getStyles() {

    var allRules = {};
    var selectorIndex = {};

    // This will map each individual class to a selector that mentions it
    // i.e. if you have a selector like ".top a", this will create two entries, one for ".top" and
    // one for "a". Each entry will point to the string ".top a", which can then be used to look up
    // the rule in the allRules map.
    var indexSelectors = function (selectorText) {
        if(typeof selectorText === "string" && selectorText.length) {
            $.each(selectorText.split(' '), function (i, sel) {
                var currentSelectors = selectorIndex[sel];
                if (typeof currentSelectors === 'undefined') {
                    currentSelectors = [];
                }
                currentSelectors.push(selectorText);
                selectorIndex[sel] = currentSelectors;
            });
        }
    };

    // Make a map of all top/left/width/height styles based on the selectors. This will be a "last one
    // wins" map -- later entries will overwrite earlier ones. If you don't want "last one wins," you
    // can use the array.push strategy that the indexSelectors function uses.
    var extractStyles = function (i, rule) {
        indexSelectors(rule.selectorText);
        if(rule.style) {
            var topStyle = rule.style['top'];
            var leftStyle = rule.style['left'];
            var widthStyle = rule.style['width'];
            var heightStyle = rule.style['height'];
            // only make an entry if there's at least one non-empty style in the list we're interested in
            if(topStyle.length || leftStyle.length || widthStyle.length || heightStyle.length) {
                allRules[rule.selectorText] = {
                    top: rule.style['top'],
                    left: rule.style['left'],
                    width: rule.style['width'],
                    height: rule.style['height']
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var extractFromStyleSheet = function (i, styleSheet) {
        var rules;
        if (styleSheet) {
            rules = styleSheet.cssRules ? styleSheet.cssRules : styleSheet.rules;
            if (rules !== null) {
                $.each(rules, extractStyles);
            }
        }
    };

    // build allRules dictionary
    $(document.styleSheets).each(extractFromStyleSheet);

    $('[class]').each(function eachClassName(){
        $.each($(this).attr('class').split(' '),function(i,className) {
            if (typeof className === 'string' && className.length) {
                className = '.' + className;
                var selectors = selectorIndex[className];
                if (selectors) {
                    $.each(selectors, function (i, sel) {
                        var found = allRules[sel];
                        if (found) {
                            console.log(className, sel, found);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do here, and particularly how do you want to handle CSS styles like this?

```
.two {
    top: 12px;
}

.two a {
    top: 24px;
}
```

Still, the code above should get you started (assuming I've correctly understood what you're looking for).